# Как напечаталось значения атрибута __a объекта c?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, атрибуты

Дан класс:

```
class C:
    __a = 42

c = C()
print(...)
```

Что нужно написать вместо **`...`**, чтобы напечаталось значения атрибута **`__a`** объекта `c`?

Comment: Два символа `_` нижнего подчеркивания перед названием переменной делают ее приватной и недоступной за пределами класса

Comment: а как именно будет выглядеть программа ?

Comment: в этом случае - никак. Это значение нельзя вывести на экран за пределами класса

Comment: Какие параметры нужно передать range, чтобы код вывел 3, 2, 1?

for i in range(...):
    print(i)

Comment: `(3, 0, -1)`, здесь первые 2 параметра - это границы, третий - шаг

Comment: кто бы ты ни был , спасибо огромное тебе

Comment: Дан класс:

class C:
    def ...(self):
        return self
    def ...(self):
        return 42
Что надо написать вместо ..., чтобы объекты класса C можно было пользоваться классом так:

for el in C():
    print(el)

Comment: Дан класс:

class C:
    ...:
        return 42
c = C()
print(len(c))
Что нужно написать вместо ..., чтобы код вывел 42?

Comment: Давайте переместимся в дискорд: `dennys#5895`

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
class C:
    __a = 42


c = C()
print(c._C__a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите, как можно найти это самостоятельно, если вы не знаете наверняка. В питоне есть такая встроенная функция `dir`, которая выдаёт список атрибутов объекта. Вы можете просто перебрать таким образом все атрибуты и посмотреть, в каких встречается искомое название как подстрока. Ну и можно сразу получить значение этого атрибута, используя метод `__getattribute__`:

```
print(*[f'c.{x} => {c.__getattribute__(x)}' for x in dir(c) if '__a' in x], sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
c._C__a => 42
```